# Xcode loading program resources from my Home folder rather than Resources - C++

Tags: c++, xcode, resources

This is my first time using Xcode and it is appalling to me how completely non intuitive this IDE is. I heard it was better in the past and I really hope it was.

My problem is that the resources my program loads, a data file and an .ini file, it automatically searches for these file in my Home folder. I want for it to search for these files in the Resource folder of the .app. I am using C++ and all of the examples I have found are for Objective-C.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably assuming that, when your app launches, the current working directory of the process is your app's bundle. It isn't. (Nothing to do with Xcode particularly -- that's just how OS X works.)

Typically you would use [`NSBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003624) (Objective-C) or [`CFBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001191) (C)
to find resources in your app bundle.  Since you're using C++, let's use the C API.

To find the URL to a file "myFile.ini" in the Resources directory in your app bundle:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("myFile"), CFSTR("ini"), NULL);
UInt8 filePath[PATH_MAX];
if (CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, true, filePath, sizeof(filePath)))
{
    // use your API of choice to open and read the file at filePath
}
```

Or, to just change the CWD to your app bundle:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(mainBundle);
UInt8 bundlePath[PATH_MAX];
if (CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, true, bundlePath, sizeof(bundlePath)))
{
    if (chdir((const char*)bundlePath) == 0)
    {
        // now the CWD is your app bundle, and you can use relative path names to access files inside it
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure what I was thinking. I mean, I know an .exe by default will use resources that are in the same folder. And I know that OSX uses the .app container. Thanks for the answer. The C version of this was what I was after and you delivered.

Comment: I hate to ask, but how would I actually use this. Now that I have the file path, what does it actually represent. How would I open a file stream to that filePath.

Comment: A file path is a string like "/path/to/my.app/Resources/myFile.ini". Do you have a particular file IO API in mind? The ones in the standard C and C++ libraries work fine, but there are plenty of others... Since you were talking about .exes and Windows, I assumed you were porting some existing code, and if that code is using the standard libraries then it should just work.